# You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse UPS

Tags: c#

i know there are other questions that have been asked like that but that seems to be different, this error happens when i want to get quote for the shipping in UPS

```
         RateReturn returnObject = new RateReturn();

         UPSParamShipmentRequest shipRequest = UPS_ShipRequest();

         returnObject = _UpsShipping.GetQuote(shipRequest)
```

shipRequest is parameters that i fill to send :

```
private UPSParamShipmentRequest UPS_ShipRequest()
        {
            UPSParamShipmentRequest shipRequest = new UPSParamShipmentRequest();
            #region shipRequest

            shipRequest.ServiceCode = rcbUPSServiceType.Text;
            shipRequest.PackageCount = "1";
            shipRequest.PackagingType = rcbUPSPackagingType.Text;
            //shipRequest.FreightClass = rcbUPSFreightClass.Text;
            shipRequest.PackageWeight = Utilities.NumberUtils.ConvertToInt(rtbUPSWeight.Value).ToString();
            shipRequest.CommodityValueCurrencyCode = "USD";
            shipRequest.CommodityValueMonetaryValue = rtbUPSValue.Text;
            shipRequest.CommodityDescription = rtbUPSDescription.Text;
            //shipRequest.HandlingUnitType = rcbUPSHandlingType.Text;

            shipRequest.UnitOfMeasurementCode = rcbUPSWeightUnit.Text.Split('-')[0].TrimEnd(); //"lbs";
            shipRequest.UnitOfMeasurementDescription = rcbUPSWeightUnit.Text.Split('-')[1].TrimStart();// "pounds";
            shipRequest.CommodityLength = Utilities.NumberUtils.ConvertToInt(rtbUPSLength.Value).ToString();
            shipRequest.CommodityHeight = Utilities.NumberUtils.ConvertToInt(rtbUPSHeight.Value).ToString();
            shipRequest.CommodityWidth = Utilities.NumberUtils.ConvertToInt(rtbUPSWidth.Value).ToString();
            shipRequest.CommodityDimensionsUnitOfMeasurementCode = rcbUPSDimensionUnit.Text.Split('-')[0].TrimEnd();
            shipRequest.CommodityDimensionsUnitOfMeasurementDesc = rcbUPSDimensionUnit.Text.Split('-')[1].TrimStart();

            #endregion

            #region ShipmentSender

            Sender oSender = new Sender();
            oSender.PersonName = rtbSenderName.Text;// 
            oSender.CompanyName = rtbSenderCompany.Text;// 
            oSender.PhoneNumber = rtbSenderPhone.Text;// 
            oSender.Address1 = rtbSenderAddress1.Text;// 
            oSender.Address2 = rtbSenderAddress2.Text;//
            oSender.City = rtbSenderCity.Text;// "Austin";
            oSender.StateOrProvinceCode = rtbSenderState.Text;// 
            oSender.PostalCode = rtbSenderZip.Text;// 
            oSender.CountryCode = rtbSenderCountry.Text;// 

            shipRequest.ShipmentSender = oSender;

            #endregion

            #region ShipmentRecipient

            Recipient oRecipient = new Recipient();
            oRecipient.TinType = "BUSINESS_UNION";
            oRecipient.TinNumber = "XXX"; // 
            oRecipient.PersonName = rtbRecipientName.Text;// 
            oRecipient.CompanyName = rtbRecipientCompany.Text;// 
            oRecipient.PhoneNumber = rtbRecipientPhone.Text;// 
            oRecipient.Address1 = rtbRecipientAddress1.Text;// 
            oRecipient.Address2 = rtbRecipientAddress2.Text;//
            oRecipient.City = rtbRecipientCity.Text;// 
            oRecipient.StateOrProvinceCode = rtbRecipientState.Text;// 
            oRecipient.PostalCode = rtbRecipientZip.Text;// 
            oRecipient.CountryCode = rtbRecipientCountry.Text;// 
            oRecipient.IsResidential = false;

            shipRequest.ShipmentRecipient = oRecipient;

            #endregion

            #region ShipmentPayer

            Payer oPayer = new Payer();
            oPayer.PersonName = rtbUPSPayerName.Text;// 
            oPayer.CompanyName = rtbUPSPayerCompany.Text;// 
            oPayer.PhoneNumber = rtbUPSPayerPhone.Text;// 
            oPayer.Address1 = rtbUPSPayerAddress1.Text;// 
            oPayer.Address2 = rtbUPSPayerAddress2.Text;//
            oPayer.City = rtbUPSPayerCity.Text;// 
            oPayer.StateOrProvinceCode = rtbUPSPayerState.Text;// 
            oPayer.PostalCode = rtbUPSPayerZip.Text;// 
            oPayer.CountryCode = rtbUPSPayerCountry.Text;// 
            shipRequest.ShipmentPayer = oPayer;

            #endregion

            #region Payment

            shipRequest.ShipBillOption = rcpUPSBillOption.Text;
            #endregion

            return shipRequest;
        }
```

solutions in other question was to "stream.Close()" after writing the stream but i can't seem to be able to control that because it is a request to UPS, is there a way to be able to close that stream ?

Comment: The question which starts with `you must` is very misleading, because it's not a correct way to make a question. Please try to use `wh-` words instead, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word

Comment: that's the error that i am getting i put it in the title, the question in in the body

Comment: nevermind i fixed it by adding     
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: btw, you may post an answer to your own question and accept it